# How does one drag an image form one layout to another layout

Tags: android

How does one drag an image from one layout to another layout. I am attaching what i have done so far. I have two layouts in a single view. I can move the image on its initial layout. But the problem is i cant move the image to a different layout. Please help me find the solution to this problem.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">   <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:scaleType="matrix" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:scaleType="matrix" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00aa00"
        >
        </ImageView>


           </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and main file is

```
package com.example.multitouch;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class multitouch extends Activity  implements OnTouchListener{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix() ;
    Matrix eventmatrix = new Matrix();
    static float centerX,centerY;
    final static int NONE = 0;
    final static int DRAG = 1;
    int touchState=NONE;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);      
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        final int action = event.getAction();


        switch(action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchState= DRAG;
            centerX= event.getX();
            centerY = event.getY();         
            eventmatrix.set(matrix);                
        break;      
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (touchState == DRAG) {
            matrix.set(eventmatrix);
            matrix.setTranslate(event.getX()-centerX,event.getY()-centerY);
            }           
            view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            //view.setImageMatrix(eventmatrix);
        break;  
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //touchState=NONE;
            break;

        }       
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please give me a reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can get really complicated, but check this out:
http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/moving-views-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

How can you move it to another layout if it's not its child? I'd try to wrap your root layout into `RelativeLayout` and place the image there, so you could move it wherever you want.

Something like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <ImageView/>
    <LinearLayout>  
         <LinearLayout/>
    </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @user639183Thanks for you reply.if you dont mind can you explain it . i am newbie that why asking this.

Comment: Your image is inside some layout, it can't get out of it by moving. So you need to situate your image in the global layout that covers all the screen. I'll update my answer.